# Is there a way to fade a Google Fonts web font on load instead of flashing once it's downloaded?

Tags: html, css, webfonts, google-fonts

I'm using a Google Font on my site with the following  tag in my index.html page:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,500&display=block" rel="stylesheet">
```

No matter what I do, the first load of the page results in a flash of changing/appearing text.

I have experimented with changing `display` to `block`, `swap`, etc.  But no matter which I pick, there's either a FOUT or FOIT.

I have also tried to use a `transition: 1s linear` (or similar) on the blocks where text will eventually appear.  It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is there some CSS I can apply that will fade-in the text once the font has fully loaded?

Comment: The `display` property does not apply to the rendering of fonts, you should change this to `font-display` either way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display

Comment: You can use "webfontloader" for handling FOUT. Have a look at a similar stackoverflow question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48591817/6517778

Comment: @Trollsyn I am using the `display` property per the Google Fonts specification.  My understanding is that in the `<link>` tag, I want to use `display` but if I am using @font-face in CSS, I want `font-display`.

Comment: @slumbergeist thank you.  I think this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `preload` feature in your `link` tag. This tells your browser to load in your files as soon as they're required

```
<link rel="preload" href="/" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Read more about the `preload` tag here: [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)

Answer (score 0):

after ages messing around i came up with this:

add a class in your css file:

```
    .showMe{filter:opacity(1) !important; transition:filter 1720ms ease-in;}
```

then add a javascript tag at the very end of your document just before the closing body tag.

include in the file

```
setTimeout(function(){
    let h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
        h1.classList.add('showMe');

},88);
```

Seems to be working for me as i was having the same issue. Can play around with the timing of setTimeout to optimize which is the number at the end(in milliseconds).
You could also add a transition onto this so it fades in more smoothly & also add will-change:auto; or will-change:filter; but i'll let you mess around and see what suits you.
forgot to mention you need to add style="filter:opacity(0);" on the h1 in your html mark-up.

another way might be to use this javascript font observer https://jonsuh.com/blog/font-loading-with-font-events/ which is only a couple of kb in size.

as for pure css as your post suggests i do not know if this is possible until css evolves & becomes more capable.