# font-face and blinking fonts

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm trying to develop a site for customer - and I encountered a weird thing - my fonts are, so to speak, blinking. To be more precise - not always - but mostly when I go t another subpage - before page display's custom fonts on headers, we can see default font for just split of a second. That creates unwanted effect.

I'm using Bulma, recompiled from scss of the newest version, and font called Museo Sans - which I serve from my server (not from Google). When I run GtMetric there is no latency in font reading and I also use a fade in script which helps a bit with the described effect, but still it's visible. Also the site is relatively small, so no latency due to number of requests or script's size.

My guess is that it may have something to do with the order of my css. I start with font-face declaration loading fonts, then I go to basic mixins and reset. I tried many things but no results. I have to add that it's not the first site I did with that particular setup - wordpress, bulma, scss.

The site's dev version is here:

https://protonads.mediamachina.net/

css here:

https://protonads.mediamachina.net/wp-content/themes/proton/proton.css

Thank you in advanced for any suggestions.

Comment: Try moving the font meta tag to the very top of the head as an inline hard coded css right bellow. and related css. It should do the trick

Comment: I want to stay with self-hosted fonts.

Comment: You still can, by loading straight from the head it's processed before anything else

Comment: Sounds like "flash of unstyled text" ("FOUT") or "content" ("FOUC"). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591817/how-to-avoid-flash-of-unstyled-text-fout-even-with-web-font-loader

Comment: Thank you Peter - that seems like a good direction to dig deeper and look for the answer.

Comment: @amarinediary - could you please let me know how to include self hosted font's in the head section? Google does it via script which is serving parts of fonts and does some other works. But I can't find how to do the same bu just simply including the font in link in the header. Would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of reading the internet's sources I got the answer. So including fonts, from external source or local, with font-display: swap; will have two results - FOUT - because we're swapping fonts after it has been downloaded by the browser, second - a bit slower loading time, as we're letting he site to block rendering until he font is loaded.

So unfortunately no good option is available. Or at least no good option was I able to find.

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: local(''),
         url('inter-v2-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
         url('inter-v2-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff') format('woff'); 
  }
```